# Add geometry field to PostGIS with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, gis, postgis

I have a database with a table called addresses. I want to add a geometry field. I could do it in pgAdmin, but not sure how it would play with Rails.

I think sql would be:

`ALTER TABLE addresses
ADD geom geometry(Point,4326)`

Then I will want to run

`UPDATE addresses SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326);`

Can I do that in Rails or must I do it in pgAdmin (or psql)?

Thanks. Newbie getting lost in the complications of mashing several applications.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using this gem [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter)? If not, you can use that and then you can add a `geometry` column in your migration file:

```
create_table :my_spatial_table do |t|
  t.column :shape1, :geometry
end
```

or:

```
create_table :my_spatial_table do |t|
  t.geometry :shape2
end
```

The `activerecord-postgis-adapter` extends `ActiveRecord`'s migration syntax to support some spatial types such as `geometry`. So, you can use `geometry` type in your Rails migration seamlessly like other built-in types (`string`, `date`, `integer` etc.) while using this gem.

See [Creating Spatial Tables](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#creating-spatial-tables) section from the gem's documentation for some more information and examples.

Comment: Thank you both for answering. I have to work back and find out if I have the adaptor. I've definitely done some PostGIS initialization. Will take me some time to sort it out. And I need to read the spatial tables reference more carefully.

Comment: I read about rGeo and didn't want add another layer of complication. The tutorial I'm basing my effort on didn't call for it http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html. 

And I need to read the creating spatial tables reference more carefully.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't created the postgis extension in my database (a serious error and created some of the frustration of things not working). To get to my database
from psql in on the command line

`\c my_database_name`

then again in psql

`create extension postgis`

In rails I had to add the correct column (which could have been done when the database was created) which is part of what @K M Rakibul Islam suggested.

`add_column :addresses, :geom, :geometry`

Now we have the column geom of type geometry. This next step is beyond what I was asking, but it is where it's leading to. Having longitude and latitude isn't enough. I did this in pgAdmin since I knew the syntax, but better if I'd done it via Rails.

`UPDATE addresses SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326);`

I now need to see if the geom field is correct. But that's not part of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

while using Rails 3.1, and you have tables with the `PostGIS geometry` datatype. These don't seem to be compatible with `rake db:schema:dump` or `rake db:test:clone` and the `rake test:*` tasks.

First of all, you need a PostgreSQL template with PostGIS functions support.

Create a **template database**:

```
$ psql -U postgres
> CREATE DATABASE template_postgis WITH TEMPLATE=template1 ENCODING='UTF8';
> \c template_postgis;
> CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Load necessary PostGIS functions into template (I'm using Homebrew, so find the paths to your PostGIS SQL files):

```
$ psql -f /usr/local/share/postgis/postgis.sql template_postgis
$ psql -f /usr/local/share/postgis/spatial_ref_sys.sql template_postgis
```

Set database as template and grant permissions:

```
$ psql -U postgres template_postgis
> UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
> GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
> GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;
```

Then, add gem `postgis_adapter` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle`. After that add template: `template_postgis` to your `config/database.yml` like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template_postgis
  database: postgis_db
```

Comment: I'm running Rails 4.2.4. I do have ```adaptor:postgresql```` but not the template and database set. But I have to see if this is changed in 4.2.4.

As pointed out in my reply to @K M Rakibul Islam I have some studying to do.